# Cast `any` to slice of base type

Tags: go

I have a type ontology that looks like:

```
type Base struct { ID: string }

type RecordA struct { Base, ... }
type RecordB struct { Base, ... }
type RecordC struct { Base, ... }
...
```

I'm writing a method which takes in an `any` arg needs to determine if it is a slice of a type which can be cast to `Base`, perform that cast, and return it:

```
func (arg any) ([]Base, error) {
  // if any is a slice of a struct which can be cast to `Base`, return the cast slice
  // otherwise error
}
```

I can get `arg` cast to any of the specific implementing structs as the array type, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this without a massive `switch` containing all "extensions" of `Base`.

Comment: You cannot convert `RecordA`/`B`/`C` to `Base`. Those record types do not "inherit" from base because Go does not support type inheritance. The record types only embed `Base`, which means that they have a field called `Base` of type `Base`. A value of type `T` that embeds type `U` (has field `U`), cannot be converted to `U`.

Comment: Note that I'm using the word "convert" because Go the language has no "cast".

Comment: Also note that type `T` embedding type `U` will not make type `T` identical to `U`, therefore _type asserting_ a value of type `any(T)` to type `U` can never ever be successful. Type assertions check whether the dynamic type of an interface value is identical (or implements) the specified type. Type assertions do NOT check if the dynamic type embeds the specified type.

Comment: You are using the wrong paradigm as reference to come up with a solution to your problem. Go is not an OOP language _in the classical sense_. There are _no_ classes, there is _no_ inheritance, and there are _no_ extensions.

Comment: In my 3rd comment there's a small contradiction. The type assertion will actually be successful if `U` is an interface type, but that's the only scenario where that would work, and that does not appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

this is a good way I can think of, I don't know if it is suitable, welcome to communicate.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Base struct{ ID string }

func (b Base) GetBase() Base {
    return b
}

type RecordA struct {
    Base
    A string
}
type RecordB struct {
    Base
    B string
}

type RecordC struct {
    Base
    C string
}

type RecordD struct {
    D string
}

func (r RecordD) GetBase() Base {
    return Base{ID: r.D}
}

type baseGetter interface {
    GetBase() Base
}

func ToBaseSlice(arg any) ([]Base, error) {
    switch v := arg.(type) {
    case []any:
        var out []Base
        for _, i := range v {
            if g, ok := i.(baseGetter); ok {
                out = append(out, g.GetBase())
            }
        }
        if len(out) == 0 {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("no element can be convert to Base")
        }
        return out, nil
    case baseGetter:
        return []Base{v.GetBase()}, nil
    }
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("can not convert to []Base")
}

func main() {
    out, err := ToBaseSlice([]any{
        RecordA{Base: Base{ID: "A"}},
        RecordB{Base: Base{ID: "B"}},
        RecordC{Base: Base{ID: "C"}},
        RecordD{D: "D"},
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    log.Println(out)
}
```